# Как в React при передаче данных передать className компоненте-конструктору?

Tags: reactjs

Есть компонента-конструктор, которая принимает данные и создаёт нужный мне Field:

```
export const createField = (placeholder, name, validators, component, props = {}, text = '', className) => (
    <div>
        <Field placeholder={placeholder}
            name={name}
            validatate={validators}
            component={component}
            className={cl.className}
            {...props}
        /> {text}
    </div>
)
```

Например создаю Input и передаю в className строку 'errorClass'. В кавычках, так как если без них - то будет искаться переменная с этим названием

```
createField('Введите символы с картинки', 'captcha', [required], Input, {}, 'errorClass')
```

Но так как я использую css модули для стилизации, нужно указать **cl.** перед указанием класса. (import **cl** from './Login.module.css';).
Как лучше передать значение желаемого класса и как нужно правильно в конструкторе его зафиксировать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот так можно передать название класса и вытащить его из объекта классов

```
export const createField = (placeholder, name, validators, component, props = {}, text = '', className) => (
    <div>
        <Field placeholder={placeholder}
            name={name}
            validatate={validators}
            component={component}
            className={cl[className]}
            {...props}
        /> {text}
    </div>
)
```

т.е. вместо явного указания ключа объекта **cl.className** передаем переменную **cl[className]** и значение из объекта **cl** будет взято по значению переменой